# How to compute $\int_0^1 \left\lfloor\frac2{x}\right\rfloor-2\left\lfloor\frac1{x}\right\rfloor dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> How to compute  $$\int_0^1  \left\lfloor\frac2{x}\right\rfloor-2\left\lfloor\frac1{x}\right\rfloor dx\ ?$$

Now, what I did is break the integral so that $$\int_0^1 \left\lfloor\frac2{x}\right\rfloor dx-\int_0^12\left\lfloor\frac1{x}\right\rfloor dx$$

Now, for the first integral , I further break it.

$n < \frac2x <  n+1 $, where n is natural number, so we get $\frac2{n+1}< x < \frac2n$ , so we break it to $$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \int_{2/ (n+1)}^{2/ n} n dx = \sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac2{n+1}$$

Similar analysis gives the second integral is $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac2{n+1}$$

So, net answer should be $-1$ , but answer key gives $2\ln2 -1$

Where am I wrong ??

Comment: Why the answer isn't an integer?

Comment: @ManishMittal You cannot break it into 2 integrals because those integrals, individually, are improper divergent integrals. In fact, you do obtain divergent series to represent the "value" of those integrals. You van so your "net" analysis, but without breaking the integral.

Comment: @UmbQbify-Key20- Why should it be an integer?

Comment: @PierreCarre, because they are integers?

Comment: @UmbQbify-Key20- Take a closer look at the function being integrated... It takes the value zero in some subintervals and the value 1 in others... The integral actually corresponds to an infinite sum of (non integer) lengths of subintervals of [0,1].

Comment: I accept that the integrand cannot be separated (for now). even if it is 0 and 1(that I didn't see because I was looking the terms individually) , on integrating w.r.t x, in 0 to 1, it should remain , 0 or 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The integrand function takes the values 0 and 1. In particular, it takes the value 1 in intervals of the form $]\frac{1}{k+1}, \frac{2}{2k+1}[$. The integral will then correspond to the infinite sum of the areas of rectangles whose base is an interval of that type and the height is 1. The value of the integral is given by
$$
\sum_{k\ge 1} \left(\frac{2}{2k+1}-\frac{1}{k+1} \right)=\sum_{k\ge1} \frac{2k+2-2k-1}{(2k+1)(k+1)} = \sum_{k\ge 1}\frac{1}{(2k+1)(k+1)}
$$

which is indeed a convergent series. Now you just have to show that the sum of this series is actually $2 \ln2 -1$.

Comment: Got it. Thanks. One more thing: why can't the Integrand be separated? (When they diverge). A link to some webpage would be enough.

Comment: Did you intentionally use opposite brackets or it's a typo? What does it mean?

Comment: @UmbQbify-Key20- opposite  brackets mean that I am excluding the point... It does not make a difference when it comes to integration. It should actually be closed on the right. Regarding the splitting of the integral, properties like the linearity of the integral only hold if all integrals exist.

Comment: For open interval, $(a,b)$ is used, right?

Comment: @UmbQbify-Key20- Yes that is one notation, but the opposite brackets are also used.